# TSQL: How to update this field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have these tables:

```
Users
   Id (PK)
   NationalCode

UserProfiles
   UserProfileId (PK) One to One with Users
   SalaryAmount

Salaries
   NationalCode
   SalaryAmount
```

I want to update `SalaryAmount` for each user inside `UserProfiles` with new one in Salaries. How can I do that?

I have tried this:

```
UPDATE Users
SET SalaryAmount = t2.Salary
FROM Users t1
INNER JOIN Salaries t2 ON t1.NationalCode = t2.NationalCode
GO
```

The above code works if `SalaryAmount` be inside `Users`, But as you can see `SalaryAmount` is inside `UserProfiles`.

Comment: then join `Users` with `UserProfiles` instead

Comment: @Lamak you mean something like this? `UPDATE UserProfiles
SET SalaryAmount = t2.Salary
FROM UserProfiles t1
INNER JOIN Users t3 ON t1.UserProfileId = t3.Id
INNER JOIN Sheet1$ t2 ON t3.NationalCode = t2.Nationalcode
GO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is another join on `UserProfiles:

```
UPDATE up
SET    up.SalaryAmount = s.Salary
FROM   UsersProfiles up
JOIN   Users u on up.UserProfileId = u.Id
JOIN   Salaries s ON u.NationalCode = s.NationalCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE up
SET up.SalaryAmount = t2.Salary
FROM UserProfiles up
INNER JOIN Users t1 ON t1.Id = up.UserProfileId
INNER JOIN Salaries t2 ON t1.NationalCode = t2.NationalCode
GO
```

Is that what you need? I would recommend you to make `UserProfileId` column to be unique in table `UserProfiles` and store Users's unique Id in Column `UserId` which is a `Foreign Key` for table `Users`

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE U
SET U.SalaryAmount = S.SalaryAmount
FROM 
    Userprofiles U 
    INNER JOIN Users R ON U.UserprofileID = R.ID
    INNER JOIN Salaries S ON R.NationalCode = S.NationalCode
WHERE 
    U.SalaryAmount <> S.SalaryAmount
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as to why this fixes the questionner's problem, rather than just a code sample, to help them understand it.